# Algolia Firebase Extension not calling the Transform Cloud Function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, algolia

I want to remove the "reports" key and its value from the "view" object. I have create a Cloud Function for this. But Algolia not calling this function while indexing documents.

```
  {
  "created":1699434507661,
  "id":"kHf3oKAOUf",
  "uid":"x3VdbQseTcZeNiDezH8Kyj3CKFH3",
  "view":{
    "material":"DCP",
    "reports":[
      {
        "jrs2GEHYI6pTFtXIrIbc":{
          "results":[
            {
              "title":"Calcium",
              "avg_overall":23.5,
              "id":"SC2s2IZ8PzhQcNzGb9PH",
              "avg_self":23.5,
              "unit":"%",
              "value":29.11
            },
            {
              "avg_overall":14.25,
              "id":"eqpg13ICjsuS53KoyE5I",
              "avg_self":14.25,
              "unit":"%",
              "value":14.39,
              "title":"Phosphorus"
            }
          ],
          "title":"Calcium & Phosphorus Analysis - (As is)",
          "retest":false,
          "publish":true,
          "file":"AAS-002-2611"
        }
      }
    ],
    "tests":[
      "Calcium & Phosphorus Analysis"
    ],
  },
  "updated":1701954794343,
}
```

This is the Cloud Firestore Transform Function

```
exports.transform = onRequest((req: any, res: any) => {
  const originalDocument = req.body.data;
  const transformedDocument = {
    // Copy all fields except "reports" within "view"
    ...originalDocument,
    view: {
      ...(originalDocument.view || {}),
      reports: undefined, // Delete "reports" key if present
    },
  };
  res.status(200).send(transformedDocument);
});
```

Here a Algolia Firebase Extension Config Page Screenshot

[image: Algolia Firebase Extension Config Page]

I created the cloud function and its working fine in POSTMAN but not working with Algolia Firebase Extension.